# Instantiate anonymous interface

Tags: android, kotlin, interface

As far as I know you can instantiate an interface in Kotlin. I am trying to do so but I get an error message saying

> Object is not abstract and does not implement abstract member public abstract fun onMarkerClick(p0: Marker!): Boolean

The implementation is there. Do you have any ideas what the problem could be?

```
   val markerDragListener = object : GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener {

        @Override
        fun OnMarkerClick(p0: Marker): Boolean{
            mapDragging = true
            return false
        }   
    }
```

Comment: `@Override` is Java; `override` is Kotlin.

Answer (score 0):

afaik you need to override abstract method `OnMarkerClick(p0: Marker)` so
put `override` modifier before `fun`

Comment: Thanks, yes, I tried that before, it doesn't work. see my updated post. If I put  the modifier instead of the annotation, it says the function overrides nothing.

Comment: @achillin In your snippet you have capitalized the function name. As the error message says, it should be `onMarkerClick`, not `OnMarkerClick`.